# Why my JLabel don't updating properly in loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, jlabel

I want to make a loading screen for my application, but the JLabel which shows how much loaded doesn't updating properly.

I created a JDialog and JLabel. I want to update JLabel text via a Thread.

```
JDialog loadingScreen = new JDialog((JFrame) null);
JLabel loaded = new JLabel();
loadingScreen.add(loaded);
loading.add(time);
loading.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));

Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    loading.setVisible(true);
    while (true) {
        if (i3 < Math.pow(characters.size(), Integer.parseInt(length.getText()))) {
            time.setText(i3 + " / " + Math.pow(characters.size(), Integer.parseInt(length.getText()))); //doesn't work
            System.out.println("hi"); //works
        } else break;
    }
});
...
t.start();
```

Comment: *"a loading screen for my application"* See also the [`java.awt.SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).

Comment: I will look, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't update Swing components via a Thread. Instead, use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), like so:

```
JDialog loadingScreen = new JDialog((JFrame) null);
JLabel loaded = new JLabel();
loadingScreen.add(loaded);
loading.add(time);
loading.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));

Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    loading.setVisible(true);
    while (i3 < Math.pow(characters.size(), Integer.parseInt(length.getText()))) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> time.setText(i3 + " / " + 
            Math.pow(characters.size(), Integer.parseInt(length.getText()))));
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
});
...
t.start();
```

Naturally, use proper syntax for the Runnable lambda - if it's multi-line, you must use a block. However, using a Thread to update Swing GUI components is [not recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Often, [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) are a better idea.

Comment: Caveat: I'm assuming your logic for handling values is correct - it looks weird to me that you would parse `length.getText()` in a loop, but perhaps it is being automatically updated?

Comment: Thanks, I changed Thread with Timer and my code works now. And there is no reason for parse `length.getText()`. I did accidentally.